# Bluetooth Pairing on Dual Boot of Windows 11 & Linux (or some os else)

Tags: bluetooth, windows-11, windows-11-preview

When I tried to [synchronize the Bluetooth link keys of multiple systems as before](https://superuser.com/questions/1469252/bluetooth-mouse-laptop-with-dual-boot-os-pairing), there was no content under the original registry path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys`.

Later, to test whether it was a path change in the registry, I paired my Windows 11 with Mac, and used [Hackintool](https://github.com/headkaze/Hackintool) to export the paired key. After searching the registry for that key, I didn't find anything.

Could someone help me?

Many thanks!

Misaka13514

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Pro for Workstations
OS Version:                10.0.22000 N/A Build 22000
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Experience:                Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.194.0
```

Comment: I think you need the Windows drivers for Windows and Linux drivers for the Linux system. Not the same drivers

Answer (score 4):

just came across the same issue and found the solution.

on the `[HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys]` folder right click and click on '`Permissions`' , add your windows user and give it '`Full Control`'
You should be able to see the pairing keys then.

Good Luck

[screenshot of permissions dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOecS.png)